# add the hours with zero rainfall

Tags: r, time-series, zero, hour

Most of the time the hourly rainfall is zero (0), this are not in the file. How can I create a complete time series with all 8,784 hours in the year. That
is, add the hours with zero rainfall.

```
rainfall$V1 <- as.POSIXct(paste0(rainfall$V1), format = "%d%b%y:%H:%M")

head(rainfall)
```

[head(rainfall)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odea3.png)

Eg. 1992-01-01 01:00:00
...
1992-01-16 13:00:00
1992-01-16 17:00:00
is missing from the file, as they have zero rainfall.

V1 is the Date (hourly)
V2 is the hourly rainfall

and here is my ts():

```
rainfall_ts <- ts(rainfall$V2, start= c(1992,01,01),  frequency = 24*365)
```

and I need to plot the rainfall_ts, is the frequency = 24*365 correct?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tidyr::complete` to create the hourly sequence and fill the missing timestamp with 0.

```
rainfall$V1 <- as.POSIXct(paste0(rainfall$V1), format = "%d%b%y:%H:%M")

rainfall <- tidyr::complete(rainfall, V1 = seq(min(V1), max(V1), by = 'hour'), 
            fill = list(V2 = 0))
```

Comment: rainfall <- tidyr::complete(rainfall, V1 = seq(min(V1), max(V1), by = 'hour'), 
            fill = list(V2 = 0))